# Category archive rewrite rule to include category/subcategory?

Tags: categories, rewrite-rules, archives

I'd like to have my category archive (*category.php*) accessible using via a url structure like:

**mysite.com/mycategory/mysubcategory**

For example, I've got "health" as a category and "smoking" as its subcategory. The following:

- **mysite.com/health**
- **mysite.com/smoking**
- (and even) **mysite.com/category/health/smoking**

all work fine.

But **mysite.com/health/smoking** gets a 404.

Is there something under Settings->Permalinks that will fix this? Do I need to put a rewrite rule of some kind in *functions.php*?

Thanks.